# Error: Column cannot be null (I have used primary key with auto_increment)

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I'm starting to learn MySQL with an online course, and my teacher says it's good practice to first create all tables, then alter the tables and insert primary/foreign keys.
I'm doing an exercise that way, even though the teacher himself has provided the answer where he wrote the primary key inside the tables, and altered only foreign keys.
The problem I'm having is when inserting data, an error shows "column X cannot be null". That's my first column, "idcliente", which I altered to be a primary key with auto_increment, and now I assume it's not incrementing numbers automatically when I insert data. I have checked online and seen about identity (haven't learned yet, so it's not ideal for me), that values cannot be null (I've inserted data before this way, when primary key is inside the table code, and it works). I'm not sure what am I doing wrong. Appreciate any answers. Thank you!

```
   CREATE TABLE CLIENTE (
    IDCLIENTE INT,
    NOME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    SEXO ENUM('M','F') NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE TELEFONE (
    IDTELEFONE INT,
    TIPO ENUM('RES','COM','CEL'),
    NUMERO VARCHAR(11),
    ID_CLIENTE INT
);

ALTER TABLE CLIENTE
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CLIENTE
PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT (IDCLIENTE);

ALTER TABLE TELEFONE
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_TELEFONE
PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT (IDTELEFONE);

ALTER TABLE TELEFONE
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CLIENTE_TELEFONE
FOREIGN KEY (ID_CLIENTE)
REFERENCES CLIENTE(IDCLIENTE);

INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES (NULL,'JOAO','M');
```

"ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'IDCLIENTE' cannot be null"

Comment: This is honestly so weird, since until now we always have inserted values this way (with NULL filling the column where the primary key would auto increment and insert itself later). The only difference is that before we started learning with the primary key inside the table. Now that I'm trying to do it with an ALTER TABLE syntax after I have created all tables, I'm getting this error...

Comment: Is everyone sure I haven't screwed up with my first ALTER TABLE command? Is that the correct syntax? For what I'm gathering is that it's actually not auto-incrementing at least, because I do see it's set to primary key with DESC CLIENTE;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code and then I took a look at the table definition:

```
mysql> show create table CLIENTE\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: CLIENTE
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `CLIENTE` (
  `IDCLIENTE` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `NOME` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `SEXO` enum('M','F') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IDCLIENTE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

You did not define the PK as AUTO_INCREMENT.

This is the problem:

```
ALTER TABLE CLIENTE
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CLIENTE
PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT (IDCLIENTE);
```

This is not the correct syntax to define an AUTO_INCREMENT column. It might be the syntax to define an optional index type, according to the syntax documented in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html. But the index type seems to be ignored by InnoDB. Whatever you type in between PRIMARY KEY and the column list is ignored.

The syntax for the AUTO_INCREMENT option goes with the column, not with the constraint.

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE CLIENTE 
  MODIFY COLUMN IDCLIENTE INT AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (IDCLIENTE);
```

Comment: Exactly what I imagined! I had several different errors trying to add "auto_increment" to that ALTER TABLE portion. When I typed this way, the query was ok so I assumed it was correct. However, I have a question: if I write it the way you posted, does it mean I'm actually not creating a new constraint (primary key with auto_increment)? I'm just modifying the column? Because if so, I imagine it would just be correct to insert the primary key detail inside the table, and not after with ALTER TABLE, like I'm doing right now...?

Comment: Correct. I always declare AUTO_INCREMENT and PRIMARY KEY as part of the initial table definition. There's no need to do that subsequently in an ALTER TABLE. Some people add FOREIGN KEYs as a separate step after all tables have been created, because then you don't have to worry about the order in which you create tables, and you don't have to worry about cyclical FK references.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES (NULL,'JOAO','M');
```

Don't supply the NULL:

```
INSERT INTO CLIENTE (NOME, SEXO) VALUES ('JOAO','M');
```

Comment: Sorry, this is the correct error: ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'IDCLIENTE' doesn't have a default value

Comment: In other words your first ALTER failed. Surely you noticed?

Answer (score 0):

Since your column `IDCLIENTE` is set to Auto Increment, you do not need to supply it when doing an insert. MySQL would automatically insert it for you.

Use insert statement as

```
INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES ('JOAO','M');
```

Comment: I have tried this, now I'm getting the error: ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: You can specify the column Names also just like @EJP mentioned. `INSERT INTO CLIENTE (NOME, SEXO) VALUES ('JOAO','M');`

Comment: I'm also getting an error for that one :/ Basically it's saying I have to insert the number for the primary key, which the program should be doing automatically *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

Auto Increment will create a unique number automatically while trying to insert a record in the table.

So Don't Use the NULL inside the query, try this:

INSERT INTO CLIENTE (NOME,SEXO) VALUES ('JOAO','M');

Use this query: SHOW COLUMNS FROM TABLE-NAME FROM DATABASE-NAME;
which will describe you the detailed information about your table structure.

Comment: I have checked with your query, which is similar to something I was doing before (with DESC TABLE-NAME;). It does give me 3 lines, IDCLIENTE which is an INT, NOME (varchar) and SEXO (enum). That's why I was using NULL, to fill in the data for the first column. I expected the primary key with auto-increment to fill it later, but it's not working that way...